# Weighted categorical cross entropy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

please I'm trying to build an NLP classifier on top of BERT but I'm struggling with data imbalance. I'm looking for an implementation of weighted CategoricalCrossEntropy. I've already seen a solution using `class_weight` parameter on `fit` function but it doesn't "fit" well with my data (I've one hot encoded them and it actually throws an error cause dict element are not matching.

Can someone please give me an implementation from scratch of a `WeightedCategoricalCrossEntropy` function allowing me me to add weights **manually** to **Tensorflow's native** `CategoricalCrossEntropy`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `__call__` method of [`tf.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy) accepts three arguments:

```
y_pred
y_true
sample_weights
```

And the `sample_weight` acts as a coefficient for the loss. If a scalar is provided, then the loss is simply scaled by the given value. If `sample_weight` is a tensor of size `[batch_size]`, then the total loss for each sample of the batch is rescaled by the corresponding element in the `sample_weight` vector. You can use it as such:

```
def compute_loss(model, x, y, training):
  out = model(inputs=x, training=training)
  sample_weight = tf.random.uniform((tf.shape(x)[0], 1),
                                    minval=0,
                                    maxval=1,
                                    dtype=tf.float32)
  loss = loss_object(y_true=y, y_pred=out,
                    sample_weight=sample_weight)
  return loss
```

These are random values but you can change the values depending on `y` so it becomes a class weight rather than a sample weight. Here's a full example of a running training loop with custom sample weights:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras as K
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Flatten, Dense, MaxPooling2D, Dropout
from tensorflow import nn as nn
from functools import partial

(xtrain, ytrain), (xtest, ytest) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((xtrain, ytrain))
test = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((xtest, ytest))

def prepare(inputs, outputs):
    inputs = tf.divide(x=inputs, y=255)
    inputs = tf.expand_dims(inputs, -1)
    targets = tf.one_hot(indices=outputs, depth=10)
    return inputs, targets

train = train.take(5_000).batch(4).map(prepare)
test = test.take(1_000).batch(4).map(prepare)

class MyCNN(K.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyCNN, self).__init__()
        Conv = partial(Conv2D, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation=nn.relu)
        MaxPool = partial(MaxPooling2D, pool_size=(2, 2))

        self.conv1 = Conv(filters=8)
        self.maxp1 = MaxPool()
        self.conv2 = Conv(filters=16)
        self.maxp2 = MaxPool()
        self.conv3 = Conv(filters=32)
        self.maxp3 = MaxPool()
        self.flatt = Flatten()
        self.dens1 = Dense(64, activation=nn.relu)
        self.drop1 = Dropout(.5)
        self.dens2 = Dense(10, activation=nn.softmax)

    def call(self, x, training=None, **kwargs):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.maxp1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.maxp2(x)
        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = self.maxp3(x)
        x = self.flatt(x)
        x = self.dens1(x)
        x = self.drop1(x)
        x = self.dens2(x)
        return x

model = MyCNN()

loss_object = tf.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()

def compute_loss(model, x, y, training):
  out = model(inputs=x, training=training)
  sample_weight = tf.random.uniform((tf.shape(x)[0], 1),
                                    minval=0,
                                    maxval=1,
                                    dtype=tf.float32)
  loss = loss_object(y_true=y, y_pred=out, sample_weight=sample_weight)
  return loss

def get_grad(model, x, y):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        loss = compute_loss(model, x, y, training=False)
    return loss, tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)

optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam()

verbose = "Epoch {:2d}" \
          " Loss: {:.3f} TLoss: {:.3f} Acc: {:.3%} TAcc: {:.3%}"

for epoch in range(1, 10 + 1):
    train_loss = tf.metrics.Mean()
    train_acc = tf.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()
    test_loss = tf.metrics.Mean()
    test_acc = tf.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()

    for x, y in train:
        loss_value, grads = get_grad(model, x, y)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
        train_loss.update_state(loss_value)
        train_acc.update_state(y, model(x, training=True))

    for x, y in test:
        loss_value, _ = get_grad(model, x, y)
        test_loss.update_state(loss_value)
        test_acc.update_state(y, model(x, training=False))

    print(verbose.format(epoch,
                         train_loss.result(),
                         train_acc.result(),
                         test_loss.result(),
                         test_acc.result()))
```

Comment: Is there some way to weigh individual pixels in an image, or do I have to calculate some average weight per ground truth tile of the batch and pass this as a tensor of size ```[batchsize]```?

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement the answer , to transform from sample weight to class weight you can do something like this :

## First one example without weight:

```
 y_true = [[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
  y_pred = [[0.05, 0.95, 0], [0.1, 0.8, 0.1]]
    # Using 'auto'/'sum_over_batch_size' reduction type.
    cce = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
    cce(y_true, y_pred).numpy()
```

## Now with weight implementation:

```
y_true = [[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
 y_pred = [[0.05, 0.95, 0], [0.1, 0.8, 0.1]]
select_one_sum_indexes = tf.where(tf.equal(y_true,1))

Class_index= tf.gather(select_one_sum_indexes, 1, axis=1)
Class_index=tf.cast(Class_index, tf.int32)
```

##### Define your weight Here:

```
weight=tf.constant([1.2, 1,10.])#,dtype=tf.float32)
```

##### Dic for class and weight

```
table = tf.lookup.StaticHashTable(
        initializer=tf.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(
            keys=tf.constant([0, 1, 2]),
            values=weight
        ),default_value=1.)
    
        weight_sample_class = table.lookup(Class_index)
```

#### Loss with weight_class

```
cce = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
cce(y_true, y_pred,sample_weight=weight_sample_class).numpy()
```