# weighted loss function for multilabel classification

Tags: tensorflow, classification

I am working on multilabel classification problem for images. I have 5 classes and I am using sigmoid for the last layer of classification. I have imbalanced data caused by multilabel problem and I thought I can use:

`tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits( labels, logits, pos_weight, name=None)`

However I don't know how to get logits from my model. I also think I shouldn't use sigmoid in the last layer since this loss function applies sigmoid to the logit.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I suggest you have a look at the [TensorFlow tutorial for classification on imbalanced dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data?hl=en). However keep in mind that this tutorial is for binary classification and uses a sigmoid as last dense layer activation function. For multi-label classification you should use a softmax activation.
The softmax function normalizes a set of N real numbers into a probability distribution such that they sum up to 1.
For K = 2, the softmax and sigmoid function are the same.

I don't know your model, but you could create something like this (following the [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/beginner?hl=en#build_a_machine_learning_model)):

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=None)
])
```

To obtain the predictions you could do:

```
predictions = model(x_train[:1]).numpy()  # obtains the prediction logits
tf.nn.softmax(predictions).numpy()  # converts the logits to probabilities
```

In order to train you can define the following loss, compile the model, and train:

```
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss=loss_fn,
          metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
```

Now, since you have an imbalanced dataset, in order to add weights, if you look at the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy#__call__) of `SparseCategoricalCrossEntropy`, you can see that the `__call__` method has an optional parameter `sample_weights`:

> Optional sample_weight acts as a coefficient for the loss. If a scalar
> is provided, then the loss is simply scaled by the given value. If
> sample_weight is a tensor of size [batch_size], then the total loss
> for each sample of the batch is rescaled by the corresponding element
> in the sample_weight vector.

I suggest you have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65200233/14774959) if you have doubts on how to proceed. I think it answers perfectly what you want to achieve.

Also I find that [this](https://pyimagesearch.com/2018/05/07/multi-label-classification-with-keras/) tutorial explains pretty well the multi-label classification problem.

Comment: Where did you get this information from? It's completely backwards. Softmax causes all the class probabilities to sum 1, and it's used for single-label multi-class classification. Sigmoid allows for each class to have its own probability, hence it being used for multi-label multi-class classification. The correct way to perform multi-label multi-class classification is sigmoid activation -> binary cross entropy loss

Comment: In a multi-label classification setting, each individual output unit is a classifier independent from each other, therefore you need to use sigmoid, and binary crossentropy, if the problem faces unbalancing (there are more zeros than 1s for every single output unit) then you can try Focal binary crossentropy or weight the standard Binary crossentropy